# Display same as richtextbox into webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, richtextbox

I am developing chat app in *C#*,in which I have one *richtextbox* in which user enters text and "gif" emojis,although animation is not displayed in the richtextbox,but I require that animation to be displayed in to the webbrowser's div element.is there any method which can directly convert the "RTF" of the richtextbox which also includes images to the format which webbrowser's div can display?if yes than please provide me link.If no than please give me any idea regarding how can i achive this.I mean copy whole content of richtextbox to webbrowser's div,which will show animation for no animated images included in richtextbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the contenteditable attribute of a div.
If you set the ContentEditable attribute you are able to write html directly to into your browser.
View this page to get more informations about the contenteditable attrbute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable
or check this. maybe this is already what you want: http://jquer.in/helpful-jquery-plugins-for-html5-websites/emojiarea/